Mesh showing through on objects after changing from EEVEE to Cycles
I'm very much a beginner and going through the Blender Guru tutorial for a donut and I'm so close to finishing but after rendering it into Cycles from EEVEE, the curved mesh is showing through on the sprinkles. I've tried asking in the Discord but no one seems to know.
I haven't really tried anything bc as a beginner I don't really know where to start with this issue. I've tried looking through answers here but nothing comes up.
Any idea how this happened and how I can fix it? As you can see the sprinkles have a ring of black at the ends from the curved part of the mesh. Help! 


Maybe you're talking about the overlapping faces at the tip of your particles, it causes bad shading in Cycles (this effect is called Z-Fighting), to fix that select the particle, select all the vertices and pres M > Merge by Distance:


Wow!! That did the trick. That was so simple. A million thank yous. :')
